Remove mailbox delegation in Exchange Server 2013
We are using Exchange Server 2013 CU23.
I use "mailbox delegation" to other mailboxes of my organisation for controlling mails when other employees were on vocation.
Now I have many links that are not needed to me. I remove delegation, but links did not disappear. I reconnect Outlook, but all links was restored, without access. I can see it, but without shows what inside it.
As I remember all this was easy to use, but now I have this strange problem.
May be some one may help me?

YES!!! i found it!!
wrote answer in some min.

@Greg Askew Please forgive me for so many mistakes.

Step by step to remove "dead links" to delegated mailboxes in outlook.

Restore "Full Access", i make it before in "ecp" console, Recivers, mailboxes, properties, delegation section, last bottom section. Add my user.

Remember Name what was shows there letter by letter.

Next run "Exchange Management Shell" PS for Exchange (admin or no i can't remember).

Command
remove-MailboxPermission -Identity  -User "Name from point 2 " -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All

Reconnect Outlook to mailbox, link will disappears.


p.s. Sry for many errors. And Tnx 2 All. Hope this may help 2 someone.

It seems that the way Outlook caches mailbox information is playing a role. Clearing the cache might be a way to go as well.
Recovering permissions and then manually removing them seems to work.
Anyway, glad you solved this problem！
